# HTML5 Video plays on macOS safari, not iOS Safari

Tags: html, ffmpeg, webkit

Everything seems to work in Safari and Chrome on the desktop. But iOS is not cooperating.

Here's how I encoded the video:

```
ffmpeg -an -i orig.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -maxrate 900 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3 homepage.mp4
```

Here's my html:

```
<video id="bgvid" playsinline muted autoplay loop src="/assets/videos/homepage.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Here's my css:

```
video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

If you'd like to see for yourself: 2606southave.com

Comment: Thanks @llogan,  but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is your CSS:

```css
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
  #bgvid { display: none; }
}
```

You're telling it not to display when the width is 800px or less.

---

As for `ffmpeg`, I recommend adding the `-movflags +faststart` output option so the video can begin playback while still being downloaded. `-maxrate` value is in bits, so you probably meant `900k`. Your video is exceeding the limits for Level 3, so just remove `-level` and let it choose the level. Consider using `-profile:v main` instead of `baseline` if you don't need to support very ancient devices and you'll take advantage of some better compression.

Comment: That's what I get for blindly following a tutorial. Thanks a million for your effort.